# Please identify this red flower

Tags: identification, flowers, seeds, transplanting, propagation

I saw this flower in a building nearby. Can someone help me identify it?

Does it have seeds for replanting in a small pot? Or can I cut one of the flowers and plant it in a small pot?

Finally, do these survive 90+ degree temperature in *very* intense sun? We’re in the Caribbean.

Do they need lots of maintenance?

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Looks like Alpinia purpurata, a tropical plant. Someone else hopefully will check. I dont know about how to look after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *Alpinia purpurata*, commonly known as Red Ginger or Ostrich Plume, but it is not an edible form of ginger. Propagation is usually done by dividing the rhizomes or bulbs, but you can also use leafy offshoots and plant those, see here https://www.backyardnature.net/yucatan/red-ging.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know much about plants... is there a "leafy offshoot" in the picture I posted?

Comment: If you  look at the pic in the link provided, that gives a hint as to what leafy offshoots or sprouts look like - can't really see a good cluster of them in your photo, but you could just try cutting off two or three tops (leaf  and stem) to see if they will root.